# How to get two different types of Sections in one document

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, section-titles

So basically I need to have two different section headings; one that is alphanumeric (A, B, C...) and one that is labelled like Experiment #1, Experiment #2, etc.

So far I found this solution that was helpful for the alpha sections. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839647/latex-how-to-change-one-of-section-numbers-to-a-custom-letter

This is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{report}



\newcounter{alphasect}
\def\alphainsection{0}
\newif\ifalphainsection

\let\oldsection=\section
\def\section{%
  \ifalphainsection
    \addtocounter{alphasect}{1}
  \fi%
\oldsection}%

\renewcommand\thesection{%
  \ifalphainsection% 
    \Alph{alphasect}
  \else%
    \arabic{section}
  \fi%
}%

\newenvironment{alphasection}{%
  \ifalphainsection%
    \errhelp={Let other blocks end at the beginning of the next block.}
    \errmessage{Nested Alpha section not allowed}
  \fi%
  \setcounter{alphasect}{0}
  \alphainsectiontrue
}{%
  \setcounter{alphasect}{0}
  \alphainsectionfalse
}%


%https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839647/latex-how-to-change-one-of-section-numbers-to-a-custom-letter

%This is for Experiment Sections to be numbered as "EXPERIMENT #__"


\newcommand{\experimentarabic}{EXPERIMENT \#\arabic}
\newcounter{expsect}
\def\expinsection{0}
\newif\ifexpinsection

\let\oldsection=\section
\def\section{%
  \ifexpinsection%
    \addtocounter{expsect}{1}
  \fi%
\oldsection}%

\renewcommand\thesection{%
  \ifexpinsection% 
    \experimentarabic{expsect}
  \else%
    \arabic{section}
  \fi%
}%

\newenvironment{expsection}{%
  \ifexpinsection%
    \errhelp={Let other blocks end at the beginning of the next block.}
    \errmessage{Nested exp section not allowed}
  \fi%
  \setcounter{expsect}{0}
  \expinsectiontrue
}{%
  \setcounter{expsect}{0}
  \expinsectionfalse
}%

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\begin{alphasection}
\section{First alpha section}

\section{Second alpha section}

\section{Third alpha section}
\end{alphasection}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\begin{expsection}
\section{First Experiment section}

\section{Second Experiment section}

\section{Third Experiment section}
\end{expsection}


\end{document}
```

I basically just tried to do the same thing to set up a new environment and then I can reset the section counter when starting my Experiment #_ sections.

This code doesn't work though, and it was important for me to have the sections not just be `section*(Experiment #1...)` because I need them to show up in the ToC, and not `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` because I need figures and equations to be like "Figure 1.1" for Experiment #1.

Hopefully somebody sees my error or has any better ideas to get this. Thanks!

EDIT: For some reason both the alphasection and expsection work when I comment the other out. They don't work together for some reason. Also the ToC for the Experiment #_ sections are super squished.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Instead of posting fragments of code, it's much easier for people to help you if you put the fragments into a small compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: One quick tip, for your logic, I would replace your, e.g., `\ifnum\alphainsection=1` with TeX's native if mechanism: `\newif\ifalphainsection` and then use `\ifalphainsection` in place of your \`ifnum` construction, toggling the boolean with `\alphainsectiontrue` and `\alphainsectionfalse`. I may come back to this question later with more thorough suggestions.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks, first time posting! I edited it now for anyone who wants to compile it.

Comment: @DonHosek Thanks, I updated those now! If you think of any more suggestions would be glad to hear them!